# ¿Es realmente necesario usar finally en las excepciones en java?

Tags: java, poo

Porque es necesario utilizar finally en las excepciones cuando puedo colocar el codigo que quiero que siempre se ejecute debajo del try-catch sin meterlo dentro de finally?

Answer (score 3):

Estás equivocado.

El código que está dentro de la sección `catch` va a ejecutarse solamente en caso de excepción.

El código que está después de la sección catch va a ejecutarse solamente si el bloque completo termina sin excepción. Es decir, si no manejas la clase de excepción que se lanza, o la re-lanzas, lo que está después del catch no se ejecuta, pues el programa sigue en la búsqueda de un bloque `catch` que la maneje dentro de la pila de llamadas.

Además, una buena práctica es capturar solamente aquellas clases de excepción que *sabemos* como manejar, y no cualquier excepción que se eleve dentro del código, con lo cual se hace común tener varias secciones `catch` con código especializado para cada clase de excepción que queremos manejar.

En cambio, la sección `finally` se ejecuta **siempre**, sin importar si la ejecución sale del código que está dentro dentro del bloque `try` de manera normal o en estado de excepción, y si es en estado de excepción, sin importar qué clase de excepción es la que se ha elevado.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
try {    
    a[]=new int[5];    
    a[5]=30/0;    
} catch(ArithmeticException e) {  
    System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error aritmético");  
    throw e; //re lanzo la excepción
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    //asigna un número válido en el try y ejecuta
    //luego comenta o elimina toda esta sección catch
    System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error de índice fuera de rango");  
} finally {  
    System.out.println("Este mensaje siempre lo veremos");  
}             
System.out.println("Esto se verá solo si el bloque completo sale sin excepción..");
```

Sugiero que *juegues* un poco con el código para que se eleven los distintos tipos de excepciones, creo que eso te ayudará a comprender mejor el funcionamiento de los bloques `try`/`catch`/`finally` en general.